# Shorten a branch

Tags: git

I want to provide some programming exercises. So in one branch (solution-branch) a have the whole code including the solution part. In the derived task-branch a deleted the solution part. When a improve the code of the solution-part a can merge this into the task-branch.

My problem is the history, I did not found a way to push only the task-branch without the history of the solution-branch to a public server. (solution should not be accessible)  Git pushes the branch until the root commit. How can I say: please push this branch from HEAD until its parent branch? Or is there a other way for solving my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your branching scheme.

Git's history is traced backwards, each commit contains the hash of its parent, and a hash IS a (hashed) commit. So you won't be able (easily) to share a commit without its ancestry.

You'd rather have a branch with the problem alone, then the solution branch would branch off it to add the solution. Keep the solution branch local, and don't push it until you do want to reveal it.

---

Now :

```
A---B---C <<< full-branch-with-solutions
         \
          D <<< branch-where-solution-was-deleted
```

Better :

```
A---B---C <<< branch-with-only-problems
         \
          D <<< branch-with-added-solutions
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. In new projects a will remember this way. Unfortunately my above question concerns a quite big software-project where I cant easily chance the branch-flow. Is there a alternative way?

Comment: @Joe9 Yeah, this is how I understood it in the first place, I'm sorry for the non-solution here, I was indeed only trying to suggest an improvement for the next cycle. I'll edit my answer if I think of a somewhat convenient way to circumvent it for this time, but  can't promise anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found now a way to discard the history. I merged the task branch with a third one with the merge option --squash:

```
A---B---C <<< full-branch-with-solutions
\        \
 \         D <<< branch-where-solution-was-deleted
  \         \
   \ --------E <<< branch-merged-without-history (--squash)
```